# How to use resource file inside page layout?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, xslt, page-layout, resource-files

I have a page layout in which following text is written:

> NEWS

I already have a resource file which I am using in one of my XSLT file to display text based on language. In XSLT file I simply write the following code and it works.

My question is, how do I do the same in page layout?

```
<xsl:param name="NewsHeading">
<xsl:value-of select="$NewsHeading">
```

Comment: For example, the second hit on google: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6d036f6a-d1e5-41ce-b5dc-f8a0060d0f5d/access-resource-file-from-page-layout

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yojoshi/archive/2012/04/29/easy-way-to-deploy-resx-resource-files-under-app-globalresources-folder-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) on how to make your resource files both localized as well as globalized

Answer (score 1):

So, from the link mentioned in my comment above:

```
    <%= SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:MyTitle", "MeResourceFile", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID); %>
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6d036f6a-d1e5-41ce-b5dc-f8a0060d0f5d/access-resource-file-from-page-layout

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use that SpUtility code above but it didn't work. Turns out following is the correct way to use resource file inside page layout.

1. You also need to make a copy of your English site's resource file and remove en-US from it. For e.g. if your English resource file name is myfile.en-US.resx then make another copy of this file by the name of myfile.resx
2. Use the following code in page layout.

   `<asp:Literal runat="server" text="<%$Resources:myfile,NewsHeading%>"></asp:Literal>`