# Unable to get Resource file key pair values in page layout

Tags: page-layout, resource-files

I have a resource file uploaded to my server, in the 15 hive.

I have pagelayout that one of my sites use:
In my aspx page i am trying to set a href links to my resource file values

```
<li><a href="#"><asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"  Text="<%$Resources:MyFolder,string_FirstName%>" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:MyFolder,string_lastName%>" /></a></li>
```

Comment: What's the exact question? You have already used Resource file in page layout in your question.

Comment: @PradipR. Yes i have but it does not get the value?

Comment: I have looked in the default page layouts of SharePoint, I doubt that the key pair your finding is not there in that resource file. Try changing that key pair to SharePoint default Resource file like `<%$Resources:cms,Article_rollup_image_text15%>`.

Comment: What do u mean?"<%$Resources:MyFolder,string_FirstName%>"  i already have this?

Comment: In my resource file my string names are there with a value?

Comment: There are default page layouts in SharePoint , in which this resource file key pairs are being used. One them I specified above. So try placing that into your code and check whether the value is appearing or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way:

```
<%= SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:MyTitle", "MeResourceFile", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID); %>
```

Take a look at this similar thread: [How to use resrouce file inside page layout?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73594/how-to-use-resrouce-file-inside-page-layout)
Or [Access resource file from page layout](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/6d036f6a-d1e5-41ce-b5dc-f8a0060d0f5d/access-resource-file-from-page-layout)